# How can I detect an autocomplete list's item selected?

Tags: javascript

We normally select a item from an input's autocomplete list by press <kbd>Tab</kbd> to next field or a mouse click but how about <kbd>Enter</kbd> key? Press <kbd>Enter</kbd> in this scenario will result in form submission.

Thanks,

Comment: Form submission? Can you show a fiddle? Form submission will not happen if you're on the autocomplete list.

Comment: Never mind, it was caused by a bug made by another in the server side code that I was not aware of. Fixed now. Thanks.